# Cannot change brightness leves on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, brightness, backlight

I am suffering from extreme brightness on Ubuntu 18.04. I have recently downloaded this version, however my brightness keys are not working and I cannot change the brightness levels. My PC is Lenovo Yoga S740.

xrandr is not working I have tried it before. It gives me this error:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Also this does not give any output:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

I have also tried to change the grub file but nothing is working for me. (I also tried to change it as acpi_backlight=video etc.)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Finally, xbacklight doesn't work too. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you `sudo update-grub` every time after editing /etc/default/grub?

Comment: What parameters have you tried except `acpi_backlight=video` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`? And please provide the output of `uname -r`.

Comment: Yeah i tried sudo update-grub and reboot my computer but it did not work.

Comment: uname -r gave me this: 5.0.0-36-generic

Comment: Try also ‘acpi_backlight=native’ and ’acpi_backlight=none’ parameters. Check if any of the parameters you've tried changes the output of ’ls /sys/class/backlight/’

Comment: I have tried them too but they are not working :(

Comment: ls /sys/class/backlight is empty

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a kernel bug. Try some other kernel versions, especially **4.19.86** and **5.3.13** without any parameters and with the parameters you've already used. If none of them works try the latest unstable kernel **5.4**. Always check `ls -l /sys/class/backlight` since if you have some subdirectories in */sys/class/backlight* it means you potentially can set the screen brightness.